# Implementing Bit Map Index on a Relation with Primary Key

Tags: database-design, indexing, bitmap

I know theoretically how a bitmap index works, how it is encoded and everything.
If I have a Relation R with a primary key, with an attribute A on which I plan to build the bitmap index,

```
Unique_ID | Attribute_A|Other_Schema
1         |    a1      |
2         |    a2      |
3         |    a1      |
4         |    a2      |
```

To access the ith record pointed by the ith bit in the bit vector, we could build an index.  But to facilitate such an access , is it necessary that the relation be sorted? Note that the Relation is assumed to be unchanging/never modified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I successfully implemented what I was trying to achieve. While doing that I realized that accessing the ith record at random (assuming the relation is never modified) was trivial and it involved no sorting. Though it is not wrong to sort and maintain an index, we could use a dense unsorted index and access the records right away and save ourselves the trouble of sorting a huge relation.

Just thought I could provide the answer so it is helpful to others.